# Unable to run npm commands with sudo

Tags: npm, environment-variables, sudo, nvm

I've recently installed the **balena-cli** package via **npm** (which itself has been installed using **nvm**) which works fine when accessed from my default user.

However whenever I try to access npm, nvm or balena-cli using sudo they all print the following error

```
$ sudo npm
sudo: npm: command not found
$ sudo nvm
sudo: nvm: command not found
$ sudo balena
sudo: balena: command not found
```

I tried using `sudo chown` on all 3 but to now avail.

Basically, none of the Node related functions can be accessed using root.
Any suggestions on how to resolve this, perhaps by the use of environment variables?

Comment: Worth reading: https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-still-66e609f5f92

Comment: I get the security concern. It was mentioned in several places. The only situation where I needed to use an npm tool with sudo was with the balena-cli since it deals with file manipulations. The sudo -s solved it more or less

Answer (score 0):

As a stop gap, I found out that running the same command after **switching to root** works fine with the following command;

```
$ sudo -s
```

However, since it's a stop gap, it would be great to find a way to run the same commands without switching back and forth between root.

Answer (score 0):

Basically once do check that have you flashed Balena image correctly and then check the network permissions and login to Balena with root and run commands with su instead of sudo then your issue might clear.

Comment: The thing is when I run it with sudo su and try the balena command, it says command not found. However sudo -s works.